# Button doesn't work in FlipView with DataTemplates - WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

I'm using Flipview and a DataTemplateSelector to determine at runtime which DataTemplate to apply to show items in my control.

I have two DataTemplate's, one is static and the second can be used by a undetermined number of items.

The problem is that the button does nothing. I've used a breakpoint in `SaveCommand` but when I click the button, it doesn't break.

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Margin="10,0,18,18"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Url}"></TextBox>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="SendButton" 
                Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" 
                Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Skins/Images/buton.png" Stretch="None" />
                    <TextBlock Text="CLICK ME" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"
        FirstTextTemplate="{StaticResource FirstDataTemplate}"
    SecondTextTemplate="{StaticResource SecondDataTemplate}">
    </local:MyDataTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <FlipView x:Name="itemGridView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}" 
        Margin="265,220,284,162">
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
public sealed partial class FlipViewDemo : Page
{
    public FlipViewDemo()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var items = new List<BaseClass>();

        items.Add(new FirstItem
        {
            Content="This is a test - Content"
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new SecondItem
            {
                Url = "http://www.google.com/ " + i.ToString() 
            });
        }
        itemGridView.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{

}

public class FirstItem : BaseClass
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class SecondItem : BaseClass
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FirstTextTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SecondTextTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is FirstItem)
            return FirstTextTemplate;
        if (item is SecondItem)
            return SecondTextTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class FisaObsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand saveCommand;

    public FisaObsViewModel()
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new RelayCommand(
                async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Message");
                        await dlg.ShowAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

*Some of the links that I've checked:*

http://www.mutzl.com/tag/mvvm-light/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18199.event-handling-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `DataTemplate` is referencing your `Model`, not your `ViewModel`. So your command binding is trying to find the command on the **Model**.

You need to change your binding source to whatever element has it's `DataContext` set to the ViewModel.

```
{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}
```

**Or**

Give your `Page` a `Name`, and use the following binding:

```
{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, ElementName=myPageName}
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your response. I'm not sure where I should use your code. Should I replace the Binding in the "Command" ?

Comment: I get this errors: `Error 1 The member "AncestorType" is not recognized or is not accessible. 
Error 2 The property 'AncestorType' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'. 
Error 3 Unknown member 'AncestorType' on element 'RelativeSource'.` I only have `Dispatcher` and `Mode` in `RelativeSource`

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide an alternative solution. I think it may be because you're using WinRT, it probably doesn't have RelativeSource (but I'm not certain).